# calling function for "new google.maps.Circle" from initialize failed

Tags: javascript, function, google-maps, initialization

Could someone please describes me, where is problem and how the code could be fixed?

This is not working :

```
function initialize() {
    var b = new google.maps.LatLng(49.190033, 16.6150523); var Copt = {center:b, map: map, radius: 1000};
    var mapOptions = { zoom: 13, center: b, mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP }              
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),mapOptions);
    cir();
    //var C = new google.maps.Circle(Copt);C.setMap(map);
} 

function cir(){    
    var C = new google.maps.Circle(Copt); C.setMap(map);
}
```

But when I put the content of the function cir() inside initialize, its working:
here

```
function initialize() {
    var b = new google.maps.LatLng(49.190033, 16.6150523); 
    var Copt = {center:b, map: map, radius: 1000};
    var mapOptions = { zoom: 13, center: b, mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP }              
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),mapOptions);
    //cir();
    var C = new google.maps.Circle(Copt);C.setMap(map);
}
```

I think, it has something to do with the  part `<body onload="initialize()">
  <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>` but realy dont understand what to do , how to put a function outside of initialize and how is this working.

Could you please create a short example of function for creating circle and call it from initialize ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem you're having is, your `C` function doesn't have the `map` variable in scope. Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
  </head>
  <body onload="initMap();">
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
    <script>
        function initMap() {
            var options = {
                // your options here
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), options);
            drawCircle(map);
        };

        function drawCircle(map) {
            // draw circle logic in here; use map as you would normally
        };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Passing the `map` parameter to your `drawCircle()` function means it can then use it. I'm not familiar with the `Circle` object, but you should be able to implement your code from here.

Comment: Hi, thank you for answer and good idea. I tried          "function drawCircle(map) {
              alert ("alert");
              C = new google.maps.Circle({center:b, map: map, radius: 1000});   
          };",but unfortunately, the problem is still the same (i got only map and alert).

Comment: If you use Chrome, you should get any JavaScript errors in the Web Inspector console.

Answer (score 1):

I usually declare `var map;` globally.  this prevents having to be passing around the map reference.